# VPN Access to an Azures hosted Virtual server

Tags: azure, windows-server-2008, vpn

I'm using some hosted 2008R2 servers for testing scenarious in the Azures cloud and they seem to be working well for most things.

I need clients to directly access the server via VPN such that they have full IP access to the server, for, say, SMB NET USE drive mappings, which otherwise would not be available over the Internet.

Normally, you'd just install RRAS and configure VPN.

But on these VMs, the connection from a remote VPN client fails.  I'm forwarding the correct endpoints (I believe), 47 & 1723 for PPTP and 50/51/500 for IPSEC.  But they aren't getting through.

The server is listening on these ports.

All my searching seems to suggest you need to use "Azures connect" for VPN access, so does this mean you can't go direct to the server for clients?  I don't want to go for the Azures Connect route as I'm just playing/testing and don't want to use any proprietory methods.

Confirmation that this is impossible would be useful to save me going mad.

Comment: Did you simply open the ports in the firewall? Or did you configure the endpoints in Windows Azure?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this?  I'm running into the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

Azure Connect is a very good way to start; it is an Azure service so I am not sure why you are reluctant to use it. I would keep an eye on performance; VPN could very well be faster. Here is my blog post on how Azure Connect works and the steps I took to make it work: http://geekswithblogs.net/hroggero/archive/2012/10/18/how-to-create-a-virtual-network-with-azure-connect.aspx

Regarding VPN, only certain devices are supported for the preview. Please refer to MSDN for a complete list of supported devices and protocol requirements: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156075.aspx